# How to increase the line spacing of UILabel in plist file

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UILabel on xib file and I am using plist file to edit its text.

To increases the line spacing, I implemented NSMutableAttributedString.
When I pass the string "Label", line spacing is increased but all UILabels will be the same text.(plist file text is not shown).

Any solution for the problem?

```
 class PlaySheetCellLeft: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet var LBLTitle:UILabel!


    var message:[String:Any]? {
            didSet{
                guard let msg = self.message else { return  }
                self.LBLTitle.text = title

 let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 10
            let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Label")
            attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
            LBLTitle.attributedText = attrString

            }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Label")` to `let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title)`. You can also remove `self.LBLTitle.text = title`.